How to create a horizontal histogram to visualize numbers based on their corresponding rows in R
data <- c(-1.66, -0.02, -0.45, -0.31, -0.42, 0.13, -1.9, 0.39, 0.66, 0.47,
          -1.98, 0.15, 0.34, -0.01, -0.25, 0.34, 0.62, -0.25, -0.93, 2.22,
          1.04, -1.35, -0.31, 0.76, 0.98, 0.76, -0.05, 1.2, -0.33, 1.47,
          1.78, 0.51, 0.91, -3.97, -0.54, -1.35, -2.05, 0.6, 0.73, 1.48,
          -1.35, 0.21, -0.4, 0.9, 0, 1.46, 1.71, 0.73, -1.49, 0.69, -1.86)

df <- data.frame(time = data)

I want to create a horizontal histogram to represent numerical data, with each number being associated or linked to its respective row in a dataset . This means that each bar in the histogram would represent a specific number from the dataset. I would prefer R basic

Something like image(as.matrix(df))?

Or like plot(df$time, type = "h")?

Thank you. I want to display a horizontal histogram where each column value is represented in its respective position based on its rwa numerical value (similar to a horizontal bar chart without graphical bars). So you will see raw number shapes the horizontal histogram.

Sounds like you want a stem and leaf plot. stem(df$time)

A horizontal histogram where each row number is positioned horizontally based on its value in the time vector

I am not sure the plot below answers the question. It creates a dot plot first, saves the plot in p then extracts the dots stack position. It uses those positions to plot the row numbers instead of dots.
data <- c(-1.66, -0.02, -0.45, -0.31, -0.42, 0.13, -1.9, 0.39, 0.66, 0.47,
          -1.98, 0.15, 0.34, -0.01, -0.25, 0.34, 0.62, -0.25, -0.93, 2.22,
          1.04, -1.35, -0.31, 0.76, 0.98, 0.76, -0.05, 1.2, -0.33, 1.47,
          1.78, 0.51, 0.91, -3.97, -0.54, -1.35, -2.05, 0.6, 0.73, 1.48,
          -1.35, 0.21, -0.4, 0.9, 0, 1.46, 1.71, 0.73, -1.49, 0.69, -1.86)

df <- data.frame(time = data)

library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = time)) + geom_dotplot()
q <- ggplot_build(p)
#> Bin width defaults to 1/30 of the range of the data. Pick better value with
#> `binwidth`.
x <- q$data[[1L]]$stackpos

i <- order(df$time)
df2 <- data.frame(x, y = df$time[i], row = row.names(df)[i])

ggplot(df2, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = row))


Created on 2024-06-21 with reprex v2.1.0

Never sorry.  Sorry. I would recommend reading my comments as they are very clear

@user330 Do you want one bar per row with row numbers in the y axis and bar lengths the time values?

No, the plot shows raw numbers according to their values in the scale. There is no x-axis scale. there is a y-Axis only, which follows the values of time only. Thanks

To make it  clear if you use geom_dotplot() you may get a better understanding, instead of  dots, you should see the number of raws

@user330 But then the row numbers would over plot and become unreadable. See the edit.

Thanks. I think making a gap between the numbers may work so the numbers can be seen parallel, like dot plots?

@user330 See the edit now.

This is indeed great. Thank you +1
